# Can I use dynlm without any lagged variables?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, lags

I am trying to use a dynamic linear regression using dynlm command in R programming since I need to analyze my panel data but I do not want to use panel regression.

However, my model specification do not contain any lagged variables at all. Can I still use the dynamic linear model (dynlm) in this case? The outputs it give are still quite good and helpful.

For instance, I get the following.

```
 Call:
 dynlm(formula = y ~ a + b + c + d*g + e*g + 
     f*g + h + i + j)

                Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept)  2.12175142  1.87591046   1.131  0.258860    
 a            0.00019267  0.02859444   0.007  0.994628    
 b           -0.01091167  0.02133546  -0.511  0.609392    
 c            0.17635258  0.05616125   3.140  0.001842 ** 
 d           -0.12717373  0.04706829  -2.702  0.007253 ** 
 g           -0.39693637  0.09144441  -4.341 1.894e-05 ***
 e           -0.15394576  0.05059879  -3.042  0.002536 ** 
 f           -0.22525696  0.07412517  -3.039  0.002565 ** 
 h           -0.10063528  0.01242704  -8.098 1.108e-14 ***
 i            0.00098993  0.00240669   0.411  0.681102    
 j           -0.11337655  0.30151860  -0.376  0.707146    
 d:g          0.06875835  0.09451161   0.728  0.467431    
 g:e          0.09787315  0.11409165   0.858  0.391603    
 g:f          0.19367624  0.14990202   1.292  0.197260    
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Residual standard error: 0.1648 on 331 degrees of freedom
 Multiple R-squared:  0.5586 ,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5452
 F-statistic: 31.9 on 10 and 331 DF,  p-value: < 1.401e-50

 Durbin-Watson statistic 
 (original):    1.34863 , p-value: 1.861e-10
 (transformed): 2.09349 , p-value: 8.068e-01>
```

The first part of the data set I use is the following:

```
 Date       ID  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h        i               j          y
 01/01/2017 1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.287199892    6.26048245  0.380978369
 01/01/2017 2   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.287199892    6.26048245  0.380978369
 01/01/2017 3   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.8 -0.287199892    6.26048245  0.524437496
 01/03/2017 4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7.8 -0.260937218    6.258402008 0.63409868
 01/04/2017 5   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 10.51545939 6.263858877 0.392317155
 01/04/2017 6   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 10.51545939 6.263858877 0.392317155
 01/04/2017 7   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   6.5 10.51545939 6.263858877 1.049993284
 01/04/2017 8   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.3 10.51545939 6.263858877 0.461989851
 01/05/2017 9   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.1 -16.12973095    6.280696169 0.69686996
 01/05/2017 10  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.7 -16.12973095    6.280696169 0.639270495
 01/05/2017 11  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.3 -16.12973095    6.280696169 0.369339223
 01/06/2017 12  1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.395179169
 01/06/2017 13  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   6.3 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.634524509
 01/06/2017 14  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.605731699
 01/06/2017 15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.2 -7.097505117    6.281526986 1.765103139
 01/07/2017 16  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.323052418
 01/07/2017 17  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.323052418
 01/08/2017 18  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -7.097505117    6.281526986 0.357581409
 01/09/2017 19  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.376295821    6.278540118 0.375177221
 01/09/2017 20  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.376295821    6.278540118 0.375177221
 01/10/2017 21  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.07381926  6.275634353 0.323677822
 01/10/2017 22  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6.3 1.07381926  6.275634353 0.529304377
 01/11/2017 23  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -15.99695552    6.292042205 0.272404556
 01/11/2017 24  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -15.99695552    6.292042205 0.272404556
 01/11/2017 25  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   5.8 -15.99695552    6.292042205 0.485387413
 01/11/2017 26  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.3 -15.99695552    6.292042205 0.651151817
 01/12/2017 27  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 4.672168917 6.290699191 0.259498815
 01/12/2017 28  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 4.672168917 6.290699191 0.396883681
 01/13/2017 29  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.247276795
 01/13/2017 30  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   6.1 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.72878018
 01/13/2017 31  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6.3 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.439525331
 01/13/2017 32  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6.3 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.439525331
 01/13/2017 33  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.674418975
 01/14/2017 34  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.228731465
 01/14/2017 35  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.228731465
 01/14/2017 36  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.2 2.818656098 6.288309121 1.614602435
 01/15/2017 37  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.247426893
 01/15/2017 38  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   7.3 2.818656098 6.288309121 0.557578826
 01/16/2017 39  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 0.393759618 6.285334223 0.27193064
 01/16/2017 40  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.3 0.393759618 6.285334223 0.85500972
 01/16/2017 41  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   5.7 0.393759618 6.285334223 0.676041272
 01/17/2017 42  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 7.88986693  6.287050627 0.271868581
 01/17/2017 43  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   5.7 7.88986693  6.287050627 0.601684565
 01/17/2017 44  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 7.88986693  6.287050627 0.561442547
 01/17/2017 45  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   5.7 7.88986693  6.287050627 0.426279123
 01/18/2017 46  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -2.816167339    6.284668375 0.247257528
 01/18/2017 47  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -2.816167339    6.284668375 0.247257528
 01/18/2017 48  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -2.816167339    6.284668375 0.247257528
 01/20/2017 49  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.240110499
 01/20/2017 50  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.240110499
 01/20/2017 51  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.240110499
 01/20/2017 52  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.240110499
 01/21/2017 53  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.255335931
 01/21/2017 54  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.511621616
 01/21/2017 55  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.658433144
 01/22/2017 56  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -0.673663504    6.279474132 0.295583923
 01/23/2017 57  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   6.5 2.407225453 6.276942114 1.536492494
 01/23/2017 58  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   5.2 2.407225453 6.276942114 0.484052447
 01/23/2017 59  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   7.8 2.407225453 6.276942114 0.781409215
 01/24/2017 60  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.218354632    6.274089502 0.321647225
 01/24/2017 61  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.218354632    6.274089502 0.321647225
 01/25/2017 62  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.307303763
 01/25/2017 63  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.307303763
 01/25/2017 64  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.307303763
 01/25/2017 65  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.307303763
 01/25/2017 66  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.307303763
 01/25/2017 67  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   4.3 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.613050528
 01/25/2017 68  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.546333861
 01/25/2017 69  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.2 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.537850062
 01/25/2017 70  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   7.8 -1.851624795    6.271387207 0.639599631
 01/26/2017 71  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.534464661 6.26891399  0.300565872
 01/26/2017 72  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.534464661 6.26891399  0.300565872
 01/26/2017 73  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   8.3 2.534464661 6.26891399  0.529403228
 01/27/2017 74  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 0.448048274 6.265976913 0.300919416
 01/27/2017 75  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 0.448048274 6.265976913 0.300919416
 01/27/2017 76  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   5.7 0.448048274 6.265976913 0.580776132
 01/27/2017 77  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.1 0.448048274 6.265976913 0.686217699
 02/01/2017 78  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   6.5 1.735858826 6.258495118 1.134076442
 02/02/2017 79  1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.678162264 6.256096701 0.246605523
 02/02/2017 80  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   5.7 2.678162264 6.256096701 0.788278101
 02/03/2017 81  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.240588472
 02/03/2017 82  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   7.2 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.504511317
 02/03/2017 83  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.367633571
 02/04/2017 84  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.265418597
 02/04/2017 85  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   6.1 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.657809188
 02/04/2017 86  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.363212341
 02/05/2017 87  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 1.153969121 6.253264176 0.508102373
 02/06/2017 88  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   6.5 1.046748087 6.250418001 0.372827574
 02/06/2017 89  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.046748087 6.250418001 0.372827574
 02/06/2017 90  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.046748087 6.250418001 0.372827574
 02/06/2017 91  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   6.1 1.046748087 6.250418001 0.755692532
 02/07/2017 92  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.1 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.669478955
 02/07/2017 93  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6.3 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.533384869
 02/07/2017 94  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   5.7 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.551575392
 02/07/2017 95  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.7 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.544694026
 02/07/2017 96  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7.3 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.466169871
 02/07/2017 97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7.8 2.572012207 6.247989068 0.352763774
 02/08/2017 98  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 0.93372207  6.245134    0.317670958
 02/08/2017 99  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 0.93372207  6.245134    0.317670958
 02/08/2017 100 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   6.1 0.93372207  6.245134    0.590983019
 02/08/2017 101 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 0.93372207  6.245134    0.288007254
 02/08/2017 102 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   7.8 0.93372207  6.245134    0.288007254
 02/09/2017 103 0   1   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 -7.364293184    6.246272494 0.322058201
 02/09/2017 104 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.7 -7.364293184    6.246272494 0.45710099
 02/09/2017 105 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   7.3 -7.364293184    6.246272494 0.618448667
 02/09/2017 106 1   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.7 -7.364293184    6.246272494 0.75533239
 02/10/2017 107 1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 2.054261996 6.243673693 0.322091275
 02/10/2017 108 0   1   0   0   1   0   0   7.3 2.054261996 6.243673693 0.619229315
 02/10/2017 109 1   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.3 2.054261996 6.243673693 0.574019377
 02/11/2017 110 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   5.8 2.054261996 6.243673693 0.576474297
 02/12/2017 111 1   0   0   0   0   1   0   7.8 2.054261996 6.243673693 0.292138684
 02/13/2017 112 0   0   1   1   0   0   0   6.1 -0.5847667  6.2407891   0.796668232
 02/14/2017 113 1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.347653035
 02/14/2017 114 0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.347653035
 02/14/2017 115 0   0   0   1   0   0   1   6.5 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.347653035
 02/14/2017 116 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   6.1 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.735497343
 02/14/2017 117 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   4.3 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.51068871
 02/14/2017 118 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   6.5 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.458087049
 02/14/2017 119 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   4.5 1.418813574 6.238033264 0.402129607
 02/15/2017 120 0   1   0   0   1   0   1   6.5 -0.041897715    6.235131309 0.308459288
```

.............

The data amount is too huge even for indentations so I stop here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dynlm()` command without specifying a dynamic regression (no lagged dependent variable as regressor). However, what you get then as output is just a linear regression, so you might want to use the standard function for OLS (`lm()`) instead.

Here is an example to show it is the same estimation:

```
package("dynlm")
data("M1Germany", package = "dynlm")
form <- logm1 ~ logprice +loggnp + interest

dynlm(form, data = M1Germany)

## Time series regression with "zooreg" data:
## Start = 1960 Q1, End = 1995 Q4
## 
## Call:
## dynlm(formula = form, data = M1Germany)

## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)     logprice       loggnp     interest  
##      3.4633       0.5239       0.3452      -2.6097


lm(form, data = M1Germany)

## Call:
## lm(formula = form, data = M1Germany)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)     logprice       loggnp     interest  
##      3.4633       0.5239       0.3452      -2.6097
```

Comment: I get the same answer even using pooled panel regression using plm. However, in either case, I get autocorrelation problem not detected through lm models. Thus I remove the autocorrelation problem regarding my sample as panel data and get different results from lm model. If so, is this ok to claim that I use dynlm model by regarding my sample as panel data?

Comment: A pooled panel estimation (e.g. estimated via `plm`) is really just an OLS estimation (e.g. estimated via `lm`). I believe you are asking a different question in your comment and I am not sure I get what you are asking. Any autocorrelation problem won't go away by just taking a differerent command to estimate the same model. There should be plenty of questions and answers about how to address autocorrelation here on cross validated and any text book should treat it. Also, I am not sure if your data are panel data (can't see from the data snip)- you would need to answer that for yourself.

Comment: The data above has time (date) component with ID although the IDs are all distinctive. Does this make it a panel data? The autocorrelation problem did indeed go away by implementing Cochrane Orcutt method which I would not use if I considered my sample as cross sectional data using lm function.

Comment: cochrane orcutt is a first order ar fixup and since your data has multiple measurememts per day with a varying time interval between readings ... you are in a tenuous situation

Comment: Then if I assume the time interval is the same while it can have multiple measurements per day, wouldn’t cochrane orcutt method still work?